# Unpopular (?) variables iterating

Tags: css

I am wondering if I can possibly iterate through css variables.
Here's the thing: I am making css-grid, and I want an item to be starting at certain column and every next (let's say, div) has that var(--var-to-increment) as a starting grid-column and there is var(--var2-to-increment) as the end column.

In styles it'd look like this: 
grid-column: var(--var1) / var(--var2);
If I didn't get to the point, let me know, I'll try to be more specific.

Comment: no you cannot, only with nested element you can simulate such behavior but no way with sibling

Comment: Was thinking more about adjacents. 
So it'd look something like nav + div{}.

Comment: adjacent or sibling is the same ... you cannot create relation between their value, the only relation you can have between value is inherit which is between parent and child

Comment: Okay, but aside that, could I increment my css variable or not? 
For each next element calc() it somehow so it remembers how many elements of that sort does the site have.

Comment: you need to understand that CSS variable is a custom property to start with and it's not a global variable ... so it's not a variable shared among elements, CSS is not a programming language

Comment: Well, I was hoping there is a use of a variable, after all. 
Looks like I am doomed to hard-code the amount of columns. Thanks for your help. Maybe someone will come to my aid.

Comment: consider SASS/LESS for such thing